# SQL Server - Self-Join

Tags: sql-server, self-join

SQL Server : I need to generate a report with expected outcome as mentioned below.

I think I will need to use self-join to retrieve the data in expected format. I have gone through all self-join examples, but still unable to find right query for my issue, hence thought to raise the problem here.

I have three tables like this:

Customer

```
ID  CUSTOMERNAME  PRODUCTINFO   AGENTNUM   TRANSID
1     Cust1         Mobile       1234       0001
2     Cust2         Laptop       1234       0002
3     Cust3         Camera       2345       0003
```

Agent

```
ID  AGENTNAME  AGENTNUMBER
1    John       1234
2    Smith      2345
3    Will       3456
```

Audit Log

```
ID    TRANSID      TYPE         LOGDATA        LOGTIME
1      0001       InquiryI     Input data      10/02/2016 18:20:10
2      0001       InquiryO     Output data     10/02/2016 18:20:35
3      0002       CreateI      Input data      11/02/2015 10:03:50
4      0002       CreateO      Output data     11/02/2016 10:04:10
5      0003       InquiryI     Input data      15/02/2016 21:44:02
```

**Expected Output**

```
TRANSID  CUSTNAME   PRODUCTINFO  AGENTNAME    TYPE     INPUTLOGTIME          INPUT    OUTPUT
0001      Cust1       Mobile      John       Inquiry   10/02/2016 18:20:10   data     data
0002      Cust2       Laptop      John       Create    11/02/2015 10:03:50   data     data
0003      Cust3       Camera      Smith      Inquiry   15/02/2016 21:44:02   data
```

- "data" mentioned has information about input that was sent and output that was received. Sometime due to any issue, there would be no output like in the case of `Smith's` inquiry.
- Also `TYPE` in `AuditLog` table is stored as `InquiryI` and `InquiryO`, which I think we can remove the last character using `SUBSTRING`.
- Need to show INPUTLOGTIME as well, which is the time when Input request was logged.

I guess we will need to use inner join with `Agent` and `Customer` table and self-join between `AuditLog` table, but its not working as expected.

Help please.

Comment: Go ahead and paste the SQL you are currently attempting to get working

Comment: What have you tried? How do you know which audit row belongs to a given TransID? Seems you have a disconnect there. Can you get the query that will get all the data as rows? From there you need to pivot or cross tab to get your columns.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange.. Sorry I had wrongly entered the AgentNum in the AuditLog table, actually there is TransactionID in AuditLog. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: How did you build second row in _expected output_?

Comment: Hi @selectDistinct.. I tried something like below, but its not working   ----------- select c.transid, c.customername, c.productinfo, a.agentname, 
SUBSTRING(alI.TYPE, 1,LEN(alI.TYPE)-1) TYPE, 
alI.logData as Input,
alO.logData as Output
from customer c
left outer join agent a on (c.agentnum = a.agentnumber)
left outer join auditlog alI on (c.transid = alI.transid) and alI.type like '%I'
left outer join auditlog alO on (c.transid = alO.transid) and alI.ID = alO.id and alO.type like '%O'.............. But this query is not giving any data in output :(

Comment: Instead of self-joins, you would do two joins to the Audit Log table, or you can use sub-queries or CASE expressions for both Input and Output columns.

Comment: Well then now this is a simple everyday crosstab, also known as conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT c.TRANSID, CUSTOMERNAME, PRODUCTINFO, AGENTNAME,
       LEFT(al.TYPE, LEN(al.TYPE) - 1) AS TYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(al.TYPE, 1) = 'I' THEN LOGDATA END) AS INPUT,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(al.TYPE, 1) = 'O' THEN LOGDATA END) AS OUTPUT,
       MIN(CASE WHEN RIGHT(al.TYPE, 1) = 'I' THEN LOGTIME END) AS INPUTLOGTIME
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN Agent AS a ON c.AGENTNUM = a.AGENTNUMBER
LEFT JOIN AuditLog AS al ON c.TRANSID = al.TRANSID
GROUP BY c.TRANSID, CUSTOMERNAME, PRODUCTINFO, AGENTNAME,
         LEFT(al.TYPE, LEN(al.TYPE) - 1)
```

Comment: Hi @GiorgosBetsos.. Your query works fne, however I am sorry I had missed one more column that is TIME in the report. I need to show LogTime as well, so when I use GROUP BY with that, then your query does not work and it shows two rows where in one row Output is null and in another Input in null. Any help..